# Navigate to a new link - R rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to follow a link on a webpage to get to the next webpage. I am trying to extract information on all planned parenthoods in TN and start at the webpage below

[image]

I would like to know how to start from this [webpage](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tn) and navigate to the webpage for the Knoxville Health Center. I have tried using the rvest package with the following...

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
URL <- paste0("https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tn")
Webpage <- read_html(URL)
Webpage %>% html_nodes("p")
```

Which gives me...

```
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <p itemprop="name" data-facility-id="2610" data-affiliate-name="Planned Parenthood of Tennessee ...
[2] <p itemprop="name" data-facility-id="3348" data-affiliate-name="Planned Parenthood of Tennessee ...
[3] <p itemprop="name" data-facility-id="4247" data-affiliate-name="Planned Parenthood of Tennessee ...
[4] <p itemprop="name" data-facility-id="2716" data-affiliate-name="Planned Parenthood of Tennessee ...
[5] <p>Planned Parenthood delivers vital reproductive health care, sex education, and information t ...
[6] <p class="site-footer-legal">\n            <small>\n              © 2020 Planned Parenthood Fed ...
```

Not really sure where to go past this point. Could use any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the links to the webpage by using :

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tn"
Webpage <- read_html(URL)

all_links <- Webpage %>% 
               html_nodes("p a") %>%
               html_attr('href') %>%
               paste0('https://www.plannedparenthood.org', .)
all_links
#[1] "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tennessee/knoxville/37914/knoxville-health-center-2610-91550"                 
#[2] "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tennessee/memphis/38112/memphis-health-center-midtown-3348-91550"             
#[3] "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tennessee/memphis/38122/memphis-health-center-near-summer-and-i240-4247-91550"
#[4] "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tennessee/nashville/37203/nashville-health-center-2716-91550"
```

You can now use these individual links to navigate further.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much! How did you know where to look exactly? If that makes sense. I'm having trouble understanding how to reference the correct portion of the webpage.

Comment: If you right-click on the information you want to extract and select inspect element it shows you how the information is stored.